# How can I export data from Azure SQL database to excel?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

How to export the azure database data to excel from azure portal, Azure query editor does not have export option like to excel. If that is not possible what are the ways I can export the data using azure connect?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly in Excel using the "Data Connection Wizard".

1. Go to "Data" tab in your excel workbook 
   [image]

---

2. In the data connection wizard enter connection details for your database server

Notice that server name has .database.windows.net in the end to provide full name.

[image]

---

3. Select one or more tables to get data from

[image]

It's pretty intuitive from here on..

On a sidenote, for your client (machine where you're running Excel) to be able to connect to SQL Server, you may need to add the client's IP address following below steps -

1. Navigate to your Azure SQL Server in Azure Portal
2. Under Security, select "Firewalls and virtual networks"

[image]

3. Add your client IP to the list of allowed IP Addresses here -

[image]

You can find your public facing client IP address by simply typing "my ip address" in google.

Comment: @Ashwini Jha, were you able to get data into Excel using steps mentioned? or still facing any issues?

Comment: How to connect if I am behind a firewall, which is blocking the port at 1433? Any web interface to connect to azure database?

Comment: no I am unable to get the data, I guess network is blocking the default port which is 1433/1434, Any idea ?

Comment: It may be a problem that Azure SQL Server isn't allowing connections to your client. Is your client machine (one where you have excel) IP address added to Azure SQL Server Firewall? If not, you need to add it or you can use a different machine that is already added to SQL server. I'll add the steps related to firewall access in answer above.

Comment: @Ashwini Jha Were you able to connect to Azure SQL Server after following the new steps mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the response I have added the firewall and It is working fine now. Thanks a lot!